# How to apply opacity to a background image without affecting child elements in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have a form with background image, but i dont know how to change its opacity.

```
<template>
  <div
    class="bg- flex h-screen w-screen flex-col items-center  bg-[url('../assets/img/global/computer-bg.jpg')] bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat"
  >
    <div
      class="mt-5 flex justify-between gap-5 rounded-full px-10 py-5 text-xl font-semibold shadow-lg md:w-[30%]"
    >
      <button @click="setComponent(LoginForm)">Login</button>
      <button @click="setComponent(SignUp)">Sign in</button>
    </div>

    <div
      class="mt-10 h-[80%] w-[90%] flex-wrap rounded-3xl shadow-lg md:flex md:h-[70%] md:w-[70%]"
    >
      <div
        :class="{
          'order-first rounded-l-3xl': changePicture,
          'order-last  rounded-r-3xl': !changePicture
        }"
        class="w-[50%] overflow-hidden"
      >
        <img
          v-if="changePicture"
          class="h-full w-full object-cover"
          src="../assets/img/loginSignUpForms/Login.PNG"
          alt=""
        />
        <img
          v-else
          class="h-full w-full object-cover"
          src="../assets/img/loginSignUpForms/Signup.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <div
        :class="{ 'order-first': !changePicture, 'order-last': changePicture }"
        class="h-[60%] w-[100%] md:h-[100%] md:w-[50%]"
      >
        <div
          class="h-full w-full border-2 border-gray-200"
          :class="{
            'rounded-r-3xl': changePicture,
            ' rounded-l-3xl': !changePicture
          }"
        >
          <component :is="cmp"></component>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The background image is in the first div. If I add "opacity-5" it affects also the from and all of the child elements. If i add bg-opacity-5 nothing chages for no reason. How to make a bg image opacity 0.05 but dont affect any children of this container div? I am using tailwind.

I tried sudo classes but it didnt work. Also, i want to stick to tailwind.

Comment: No because i want to use tailwind and doesnt mix tailwind and vanilla css

Comment: If you read the question and responses, you would learn there is no way to achieve this without using hacky CSS tricks. Opacity is a property that cascades to all child elements. Whether you use Tailwind or not doesn't matter.